# Как исправить смещение на графике?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

На основе данных [Таблицы](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bjXH5aP1QgrfU6k8lENnT-OcxNLFRKp0/view?usp=sharing) был построен  упорядоченный график ящиков с усами . Однако, при добавлении функции средней (строка 11), график смещается, почему?

```css
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\cinem\Desktop\нир\3-6.xlsx')
r = df.pivot_table(columns='town_name', index='cld_year',
                   values='относительная заболеваемость на 1000 чел.',
                   aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
aq = r.median().sort_values().index
ae = r.mean().sort_values().index
r[aq].plot.box(rot=90, figsize=(16,10))
r[ae].mean().plot(kind='line', color='orange', rot=90)
plt.ylabel('Относительная заболеваемость на 1000 чел.')
plt.xlabel('город')
plt.title('Относительная заболеваемость на 1000 человек в городах РФ')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Со средней]
[image: Без средней]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = df.pivot_table(columns='town_name', index='cld_year',
                   values='относительная заболеваемость',
                   aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
idx = r.mean().sort_values().index
r = r[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10))

r.plot.box(rot=90, ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), r.mean(), color='orange')
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), r.median(), color='green')
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
plt.legend(['mean','median'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]